# Using IEnumerable FirstOrDefault within a List extension method?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use IEnumerable FirstOrDefault within a List extension method? I am getting the error 'List does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefault'?

```
using LanguageExt;
using System;
using System.Linq;


public static class Question
{

    public static Option<T> Lookup<T>(this List<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            return Option<T>.None;
        }

        var val = enumerable.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        return val == null ? Option<T>.None : Option<T>.Some(val);
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        bool isOdd(int i) => i % 2 == 1;

        var none = new List<int>().Lookup(isOdd); // => None
        var some = new List<int> { 1 }.Lookup(isOdd); // => Some(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added namespace called `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq` to namespace declarations?

Comment: yes I have added it already

Comment: Then your issue is not reproducible. Which .NET version are using so far?

Comment: I have this config: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LanguageExt.Core" Version="3.4.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Should I be using a different version?

Comment: `LanguageExt.Core` has own `FirstOrDefault` method

Comment: should it still work?

Comment: Share your code with namespaces or try to use syntax from answer below

Comment: sorry I have added the namespaces now

Comment: using LanguageExt;
using System;
using System.Linq;

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is possible to use FirstOrDefault on any enumerable sequence, so also on Lists.

The following works:

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = isOdd;
List<int> integerSequence = new List<int>();
var a = integerSequence.FirstOrDefault();
var b = integerSequence.Where(i => predicate(i)).FirstOrDefault();
var c = integerSequence.FirstOrDefault(i => predicate(i));
```

So I can't reproduce your problem. I see other problems though.

If you don't understand the this keyword, read [Extension Methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx). Whenever you think: damn, I wish they had thought of this LINQ method, consider creating an extension method.

So your Lookup method is an extension method that takes a list and a predicate as input.. Since it seems that it can work on any enumerable sequence, let's not limit ourselves to `List<T>`, let's accept any enumerable sequence, like Arrays, Dictionaries, Lookup-tables, etc.

Furthermore, LINQ methods are most reusable if you let them return a sequence or result items, and let your called decide whether he wants all items, or only the FirstOrDefault, or maybe the Last, or Average.

So if you decide to create an extension method that takes an enumerable sequence as input, let it return an Enumerable sequence whenever possible, even if the sequence is empty: avoid returning null, if you mean: there are no elements matching what you want. Because that would mean that callers should have to check the result before they can continue concatenating other LINQ methods.

Finally: LINQ methods usually don't except null sources as input, they throw exceptions. LINQ methods expect callers to make sure the input is not null. Of course you are free to deviate from this, but callers don't expect it when using LINQ like methods.

With these guidelines in mind, consider to change your extension method.

Apparently, if an element in your input sequence equals null, you want to return `Option<T>.None`, otherwise you want `Option<T>.Some(val)`

```
public static Option<T> ToOption<T>(this T sourceElement)
{
    return sourceElement?.Option<T>.Some(sourceElement) ?? Option<T>.None;
}
```

In words: if sourceElement equals null, return `Option<T>.Some(sourceElement)`, otherwise return `Option<T>.None`

In LINQ it is quite normal to create extension methods with equality comparers, this will make your methods even more reusable. Usually this will only need two or three lines of code:

```
public static Option<T> ToOption<T>(this T sourceElement)
{
    return ToOption(sourceElement, null);
}
public static Option<T> ToOption<T>(
    this T sourceElement,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    if (comparer.Equals(sourceElement, null)
        return Option<T>.None;
    else
        return Option<T>.Some(sourceElement);     
}
```

In the methods below I won't mention this possibility over and over again.

```
public static IEnumerable<Option<T>> ToOptions<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // TODO: throw exception if input null
    return source.Select(sourceElement => sourceElement.ToOption());
}

public static IEnumerable<Option<T>> ToOptions<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    // No need: check if source == null, this is done in the other ToOptions
    // TODO: exception if predicate equals null
    return source.Where(sourceElement => predicate(sourceElement))
                 .ToOptions();
}
```

Simple usage:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = ...
MyClass myFirstEligableCustomer= customers
    .ToOptions(customer => customer.Address.City == "New York")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or intertwined with other LINQ methods:

```
var result = customers.
    .GroupBy(customer => customer.Birthday.Year)
    .OrderBy(customerGroup => customerGroup.Key)
    .ToOptions(customerGroup => customerGroup.Key)
    .ToDictionary(customerGroup => customerGroup.Key,       // Key
                  customerGroup => customerGroup.ToList);   // Value
```

The result is a Dictionary, where the key is the Year of a birthday, and the value is the list of all `Option<Customer>` that are born in this year.

You see: most methods are barely more than one-liners. They are easy to reuse, easy to change, easy to test.